# Groovy + Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have a simple question regarding groovy with eclipse. I downloaded the plugin as mentioned and i didnt have problems with installations but i have compiler errors in hello p. the problem in my opinion that eclipse isnot using the groovy compiler. but i have no idea what to do

Comment: Have you tried following groovy eclipse tutorial ? (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Create+Your+First+Groovy+Project)

Comment: Yeah of course :) but as iam saying the problem is that eclipse compiler doesn't recognize the groovy keywords like "def". So it always generate an error. I followed all the tutorials for creating a hello project. They are straight forward, but i don't know where is the problem !

Answer (score 1):

Is the filename extension .groovy?
Are you sure the project has the Groovy nature? (right-click on the project, and ensure Remove Groovy Nature appears. If Add Groovy nature appears, then the project doesn't have a groovy nature, and therefore the groovy compiler won't work).

Could you also post the file that isn't compiling. There might be something wrong with what you typed.

Comment: the file name extension is .groovy , the project is groovy with "gr" label , i tried to revert it to normal java project then convert it back to groovy from configure, it is a groovy hellos project. Eclipse is saying that it has errors regarding "def" and "println". It doesnt know that this is a groovy file :) any help not the straight forward ones would be appreciated. I dont want to use another IDE as i want to use GAE later

class FirstGroovyClass {
 static void main(def args) {
   def mygreeting = "Hello World"
   println mygreeting
   
}
}

Comment: What version of Eclipse and plugin? Sounds like you might have found an incompatibility. Are you using Eclipse or MyEclipse? As a next step, you might want to try downloading STS from SpringSource, and opening your initial project. It might show an issue. Otherwise, you might get better results from a Groovy Eclipse plugin mailing list. Sorry, don't have any further ideas

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are opening the file in a Groovy editor.

Look for any exceptions in your error log.

Also, just in case, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin.  I'd recommend using the latest milestone version as that one is about to be promoted to 2.1.2 final.

http://dist.springsource.org/milestone/GRECLIPSE/e3.6/

Comment: I tried it now on my windows machine and everything worked fine :). I guess i will install fresh eclipse and do the same thing on my mac machine. I will let you know with the results:)

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that Groovy plugin isnot workingn on mac. I tried it on 2 machines and they are giving the same error. Groovy plugin is working on windows without problems :)

Comment: I was mistaken, the problem isnot related to mac but rather with the latest version of groovy plugin. A workaround to this problem is to install this snapshot. please follow this link 

[link](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1003?focusedCommentId=259595&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is a better option for Groovy+Java development. You can mix Java and Groovy files in a Java project in NetBeans. It also creates a distributable jar for your project. No classpath and jar issues with NetBeans created MET-INF file.